# typescript defining array with named objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, types

I am struggling  to define a type for the
array with named objects

below is the sample code.

now i have to define the type for the `s` in `typescript`

```
 let s =[12,3,4]
 s['data']={'x':0}
 console.log(s) // [12,3,4,data:{'x':0}]
```

now how to define the  `type` for the `s`

can anyone please guide

Comment: While technically *possible*, an array *doesn't have "named objects"*!

Comment: are you taking about typescript?

Comment: Typescript and Javascript. An array is an object, like almost everything, and you can set arbitrary properties on objects, which is why this technically works. But `data` is not in any way something to do with an *array*.

Comment: please refer to
https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-area-chart

in that there is an  array ```series``` please expand it.. you will see that array has object named with ```data```

Comment: ShivaSai - Right. @deceze said (twice) that it's *possible*. It's just not a good idea in most cases.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but i can't help it.. that the library which is doing the bad stuff. since we use typescript now i don't have any option to create a type for that

Comment: @ShivaSai - Absolutely. If you're dealing with a library that gives you this (or needs you to give it this), and you need to model it in TypeScript, you're stuck with it. :-) (That's why I answered the question.)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best not to do this. But you *can* do it, by using an [*intersection type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types), in this case:

```
type AugmentedNumberArray = number[] & {
    data?: {x: number};
};
```

That's a type that's both a number array and an object with an optional `data` property that can be an object with an `x` property with a number value.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggrgcwLYQHbAgEwHJyQIwgCcYiiBDEKAXilT0KIG0BdKAMigG8AoKfqJnLByAfgBc3AB6T6BYgF8A3D2U8eAGwjAoAZ0nxkaDDgbFSFKrSYBGAEwAaAMwOALCxW6mAciEjvbLRc3lLe4gAMylAA9NFQAPJEUACWmMkA9kjCyQDG5BoaIJK6AHR+5DRQJdU8OemouulaJRrpCAAUugCUSkA)

But as soon as you do something like `s2 = s.map(v => v * 2)`, you'll lose the `data` property, because `map` (like all array methods) only deals with the array-like part of the object, not any other properties it may have.

**Instead**, though, I'd recommend defining an object that has both the named properties (`data` or whatever) and an array of numbers:

```
interface MyType {
    data?: {x: number};
    values: number[];
}
```

Then using it like this:

```
let s: MyType = {values: [12,3,4]};
s['data'] = {'x':0}; // Or idiomatically: s.data = ...
console.log(s);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMicgCZxhwD8AXMvgB70gCuAtgEbQC+A3MVIA3OABtWEAM4sO3KAG0AugJ6FCoiGGTS0WXCgC8DEeKn15ARgBMAGgDMNgCyL+hSfIDkFKh8XIj+B6MHrQADPzIAPSRyADyUMjAZMAA9uyUwAhiouj0kgB03nD+yPllhAgpIJIpGvmiKQDmABSSAJR8QA)

Comment: hey can i define the ```data``` to the array in declaration it self?

instead of  reassigning after wards

Comment: @ShivaSai - I'm afraid not, there's no way to create a non-element property with an array literal. The best you can do is something like this: `s = Object.assign([12, 3, 4], {data: {x: 0}});` More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign